# Body tag is not rendering in inspect elements in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome

[image: You can see in the image that body tag is not showing although proper body html code is written.]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Win the week web portal portal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='main.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <img class="img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/image.png')}}" id="sideimage">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="container"  id ="inbound1">
    <h3 id="tophead1">WELCOME TO</h2><br>
    <h2 id="tophead2">Win The Week Web<sup id="sup">TM</sup> Portal</h2>
    <h5 id="tophead3">Scorecard</h5>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png')}}" id="logo">
   </div>
   <div class="container"  id ="inbound2">
    <form action="#" method="post" name="formdata">
     <label for="username" id="label1"><strong>Username:</strong></label>
     <input type="email" name="username" id="username" required>
     <br>
     <label for="password" id="label2"><strong>Password:</strong></label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
     <br>
     <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login" name="login" type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
     </div>
     <h4 id="tophead4" ><a href="/" id="forgot">Forgot password?</a>


    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above does contains the body part but it is not showing in the debugger console. I tried remove caching, installing different browsers, but all in vain.

I am trying to learn flask and that is why the url path is specified differently.

Comment: im confused at what you're asking? I can see body in console.. and its children are contained in that `...` icon - have you tried clicking htat?

Comment: Yeap i tried clicking that ofcourse, but nothing is showing in that. Its all empty. But if i do check the source code, it will show complete code.

Comment: You don't have a close script tag at the last script in the head tag, which might causing the that issue

Comment: I've seen some part of the head tag was placed inside the body tag like meta tags, when I inspect element.

Comment: @bdalina thanks for that script tag, i did it and not any improvement.

Comment: @bdalina and if you can see the content inside the body tag, then the question is solved. Plus i have crosschecked as no meta tag is inside the body. :-P

Comment: have you checked console for errors?

Comment: This is what i have seen, https://ibb.co/emefVe  I have copied the code and run it in my browser!

Comment: When I close the script tag, it fix the issue

Comment: the issue is in my system only i guess @bdalina because same code is running in a different pc.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

yeah the console is showing no errors or any other thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `</script>` tag in your header this will fix the problem you are having.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Win the week web portal portal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='main.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/image.png')}}" id="sideimage">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="container"  id ="inbound1">
                <h3 id="tophead1">WELCOME TO</h2><br>
                <h2 id="tophead2">Win The Week Web<sup id="sup">TM</sup> Portal</h2>
                <h5 id="tophead3">Scorecard</h5>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png')}}" id="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="container"  id ="inbound2">
                <form action="#" method="post" name="formdata">
                    <label for="username" id="label1"><strong>Username:</strong></label>
                    <input type="email" name="username" id="username" required>
                    <br>
                    <label for="password" id="label2"><strong>Password:</strong></label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <br>
                    <div class="container">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login" name="login" type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <h4 id="tophead4" ><a href="/" id="forgot">Forgot password?</a>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did it and no improvement.

Comment: I can see the body on my machine... try clearing cache on your browser

Comment: I tried deleting cache to installing new browser. But all in vain. The web page is not showing at all. But when i do Ctrl+U, the code is showing completely plus even the title is showing on the web page.

Comment: In that case i doubt its a code error you are facing what browser are you trying to work on?

Comment: I am currently using chrome and firefox, but the problem is happening only in my system. Same code in different system was working fine.